# Playing a channel whilst recording another in Sound Forge

Tags: audio-recording, audio, software, home-studio

Basically, I'm doing some recording in sound forge pro 10. I have 4 channels, 2 of which have the backing track on and the other 2 are to be recorded on. Is there any way that I can play the backing track whilst I am recording to the other 2 channels? I can select play, but then the record button becomes deactivated.

It would make my life much easier if I can play the backing track whilst recording the vocals as then I won't have to realign the vocals to match the backing track once recorded.

Comment: In Reaper the tracks not selected for recording play back automatically when recording.  Have you tried just hitting record to see what happens?

Comment: @FriendOfGeorge Unfortunately it doesn't playback when recording :-(

Comment: Sound Forge is simply not aimed at this kind of workflow. Use a DAW, Reaper is positively recommendable.

Comment: ... or Sony Vegas if you are in Sound Forge.... it makes sense to stay in the same suite.

Answer (score 1):

Sound Forge doesn't have that option, as I recall. You should use an application designed for multitrack recording, rather than a wave editor. My advice is to use, if you are amateur in audio production, [Cockos Reaper](http://reaper.fm). Very small by size but it's very effective. If you have some experience in audio production you could use for example Cubase, or Nuendo or some similar application.

Answer (score 0):

If you do 5.1 channel audio in sound forge instead of 2 channel, you can use each channel as a multitrack recorder of sorts.